# Return List(T) from Library in c#

Tags: c#, list, n-tier-architecture

i'm new with c# and i have to import List(T) from my library to main and i get this error...

Error : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

MAIN CODE

```
List<EstatisticasEquipas> listEstatisticaEquipas = new List<EstatisticasEquipas>();
            listEstatisticaEquipas = EstatisticasEquipas.InserirEstatisticasEquipas(listEstatisticaEquipas, listEquipas, listJogos);
```

CLASS LIBRARY CODE

```
public static List<EstatisticasEquipas> listEstatisticaEquipas;

        public EstatisticasEquipas()
        {
            listEstatisticaEquipas = new List<EstatisticasEquipas>();

        }

*** METHODS ***

public static List<EstatisticasEquipas> InserirEstatisticasEquipas(List<EstatisticasEquipas> listEstatisticaEquipas, List<Equipa> listEquipas, List<Jogos> listJogos)
        {
            List<EstatisticasEquipas> listEstatisticaEquipa = new List<EstatisticasEquipas>();

            foreach (Equipa equipa in listEquipas)
            {
                foreach (Jogos jogo in listJogos)
                {
                    if (equipa.Nome.Equals(jogo.EquipaCasa))
                    {
                        EstatisticasEquipas estEquipaCasa = listEstatisticaEquipas.Find(x => x.Equipa.Nome.Contains(jogo.EquipaCasa));
                        if (estEquipaCasa == null)
                        {
                            listEstatisticaEquipas.Add(new EstatisticasEquipas(equipa));
                            estEquipaCasa = listEstatisticaEquipas.Find(x => x.Equipa.Nome.Contains(jogo.EquipaCasa));
                            estEquipaCasa.JogoCasa(jogo.GolosEquipaCasa, jogo.GolosEquipaFora);
                            estEquipaCasa.CalPontos(jogo.GolosEquipaCasa, jogo.GolosEquipaFora, 'c');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            estEquipaCasa = listEstatisticaEquipas.Find(x => x.Equipa.Nome.Contains(jogo.EquipaCasa));
                            estEquipaCasa.JogoCasa(jogo.GolosEquipaCasa, jogo.GolosEquipaFora);
                            estEquipaCasa.CalPontos(jogo.GolosEquipaCasa, jogo.GolosEquipaFora, 'c');
                        }
                    }
                    if (equipa.Nome.Equals(jogo.EquipaFora))
                    {
                        EstatisticasEquipas estEquipaFora = listEstatisticaEquipas.Find(x => x.Equipa.Nome.Contains(jogo.EquipaFora));
                        if (estEquipaFora == null)
                        {
                            listEstatisticaEquipas.Add(new EstatisticasEquipas(equipa));
                            estEquipaFora = listEstatisticaEquipas.Find(x => x.Equipa.Nome.Contains(jogo.EquipaFora));
                            estEquipaFora.JogoFora(jogo.GolosEquipaCasa, jogo.GolosEquipaFora);
                            estEquipaFora.CalPontos(jogo.GolosEquipaCasa, jogo.GolosEquipaFora, 'f');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            estEquipaFora = listEstatisticaEquipas.Find(x => x.Equipa.Nome.Contains(jogo.EquipaFora));
                            estEquipaFora.JogoFora(jogo.GolosEquipaFora, jogo.GolosEquipaCasa);
                            estEquipaFora.CalPontos(jogo.GolosEquipaCasa, jogo.GolosEquipaFora, 'f');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return listEstatisticaEquipas;

        }
```

The error is given in this method... 
Error : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
public static void TotalPontos()
        {
            listEstatisticaEquipas.Sort((x, y) => y.Pontos.CompareTo(x.Pontos));
            foreach (EstatisticasEquipas estEquipa in listEstatisticaEquipas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(estEquipa.Equipa.Nome + " - " + estEquipa.Pontos);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Too bad NullRef questions will be refered to a duplicate. This will probably not help you. The problem with your code is that the field `listEstatisticaEquipas` is static and the `InserirEstatisticasEquipas` method is also static.
By accessing the `listEstatisticaEquipas` field using the static mehod, the list is *never* created. It will only be constructed whenever you create an instance of that class. Even worse; each instance will recreate/overwrite it!. *It's a bad design*. If you insist using static, you should change "`public EstatisticasEquipas()`" to "`static EstatisticasEquipas()`".

Comment: Thank you, appreciate. I change "public EstatisticasEquipas()" to "static EstatisticasEquipas()" and no more error. But the data is not printed, i think maybe is not been imported into the list

Comment: You only add it to the list when die `if` condition is `true`